# How to change Expo entry point properly?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to change entry point of my expo app. I have tried these simple steps:

First of all, I have created a simple expo project.

```
$ expo init test
$ cd test
$ rm App.js
$ mkdir src
$ touch src/App.js
```

I have changed app.json of my expo based app as follows

```
{
    "expo": {
        ...,
        entryPoint: "./src/App.js",
        ...
    }
}
```

Then i have filled the App.js as folows

```
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";

export default () => <Text>Hello World</Text>;
```

However, the first trial have been failed. It have shown only splash screen.

Then i have edited the App.js as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";

const App = () => <Text>Hello World</Text>;

registerRootComponent(App);
```

I have seen "Hello World" text in the screen. However, hotreloading have not been working.
Then i have modified main entry in package.json

```
"main": "./src/App.js",
```

In this way hot reloading is working in second save action.

I am wondering

- How can i solve hot reloading problem (in first save action)?
- What is the difference between app.json's entryPoint and package.json's main field?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read this article:

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/#what-if-i-want-to-name-my

and be sure you restarted your whole dev process

Comment: I have followed the documentation line by line, but nothing has been changed